# Create project specific mappings and abbreviations

Tags: vimrc, autocompletion

When I'm working in a project it would be useful to be able to set some abbreviations / mappings that are specific only to that project.

I know that I can have file specific mappings in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin`

But how would I make it so that certain mappings only in the project I'm working.

So say I have `~/Foo/Bar` , `Bar` being the project that I'm working in.

I could then have some file `.vimProjectConfig` in `Bar`.

In `.vimProjectConfig` I could have something such as :

```
iabbrev ah Aldous Huxley
```

Or other `nnoremap` settings, etc.